# Remove a file from a PR

Tags: git, pull-request

Checked all the similar entries, this one is slightly different.

I have a PR that represents a number of commits (let's say 20). There are 3 or 4 files that did not change and so I'd like to pull them out of the PR. Is that possible without breaking anything?

I also have one or two that should have been deleted. Can I pull them out and then delete them?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, here is the situation. There are 20 commits. In a few (say #7, #10 and #15) there are files I'd like to remove from the commit. I could revert those commits and make the change and recommit the other files, but I'm concerted that will "overwrite" the changes that came later. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental?

Comment: A pull request (merge) doesn't affect work that comes later. I suggest you create some test branches from your two existing branches and do some experimenting as practice. Do the merge that would result from the PR and look at the state of things.

Comment: @isherwood  thanks for taking the time. I don't think I'm making myself clear.  If I have a commit that affects two files, after which there are more commits that also affect those two files. Now, I want to remove one of those files from the pr but I don't want to change the other file or lose anything that happened to that file later.  I'm right on the edge of understanding what will happen...

Comment: You're quite clear. The only way to remove files from a PR is to remove the changes _to_ those files. How you do that is up to you. Have you tested it yet? It's a very simple thing to clone both branches and try it out.